# I am trying to modify a plugin and am adding Jquery, but it does not seem to be executing

Tags: jquery

I just have a button

```
echo "<br><input type='button' value='Update Totals' id='update'>";
```

and I have some Jquery code that I want to execute when this runs. I really want to total some text box entrys but at this point I would like to confirm that I can get this Jquery to execute at all.

so I have modified the Jquery to just be an alert when the button is clicked but nothing appears to happen.

```
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'> </script>
<script>
            jquery('#update').click( function() { alert('clicked'); });
});

</script>"
```

Comment: `});` appears to be double, leading to an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to capitalize the `Q` of `jQuery` in your code. The current code will likely throw an error like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined
```

Your code also has one to many `});` which will likely trigger

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Don't forget to check the javascript console in your browser's developer tools, this is where such error will appear and give you helpful information about what went wrong.

This will work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery('#update').click( function() { alert('clicked'); });
</script>
```

...as long as jQuery is loaded and available on your page.

If jQuery is loaded in the footer, your inline code won't work because jQuery won't be available yet when it tries to run.
Possible solutions would be:

- Make jQuery load from the header instead.
- Make your code load in the footer after jQuery itself, instead of inlining it.

If jQuery is not loaded at all on your site, you'll need to add it.
jQuery is bundled with WordPress and already registered by default in WordPress, so you would just need to enqueue it with this function (in your plugin or theme's `functions.php` file):

```
/**
 * Enqueues jQuery on the front-end.
 */
function my_enqueue_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_jquery' );
```